# How to combine the result of dataframe produced in the for loop?

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance, alpha-vantage

I am trying to extract stock closing price and concatenate them into the same dataframe (in python) and using a for loop. For excample :

```
url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=AAPL&apikey={api}'
r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    Hist = data['Time Series (Daily)']
    Hist = pd.DataFrame(Hist)
    Hist = pd.DataFrame.transpose(Hist)
    stock_list1= Hist.iloc[:, 3]

url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=BX&apikey={api}'
r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    Hist = data['Time Series (Daily)']
    Hist = pd.DataFrame(Hist)
    Hist = pd.DataFrame.transpose(Hist)
    stock_list2= Hist.iloc[:, 3]
    
    stock_list = pd.concat([stock_list1,stock_list2], axis = 1)
```

is there any way I could do this in a for loop ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example doesn't seem to have correct indentation (white space matters in Python).

What you want is to store your mini dataframes in a list, and in the end concatenate them into your final dataframe; appending to an existing dataframe isn't recommended.

```py
urlfmt = f"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol={{ticker}}&apikey={api}"
tickers = "BX AAPL".split()
lodf = []
for ticker in tickers:
    data = requests.get(urlfmt.format(ticker=ticker)).json()
    Hist = pd.DataFrame(data['Time Series (Daily)']).T
    lodf.append(Hist.iloc[:, 3])

stock_list = pd.concat(lodf, axis=1)
```

Comment: looks like the `tickers` variable is not specified

Comment: @GreyMurav Well, I don't know what tickers the OP wants to include, so I assumed they can define it (just like the API key).  I have now put a placeholder definition based on the code snippet in the question.